# Data insert without page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert my data into database without page reloading but there may some issues. Here is my code

My problem is that, I can not send data in the database via my appended form in `index.php`, also when click the submit button, there is nothing happened, I don't know what I do..!

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform" action="db.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>



</body>
</html>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            if(name == '' && email =='')
            {
                $('#result').html('<span>all fields are required</span>');
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url :"db.php",
                    method :"POST",
                    data :$('#myform').serialize();
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $('#result').html('<span>loading..!</span>');
                    },


                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`db.php`

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sampl1");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "insert into jquery (name,email) values('$name','$email')";
$res =mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($res)
{
    echo "<p>you have entered</p>";
    echo "<p>name :".$[name]."</p>";
    echo "<p>email :".$[email]."</p>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: use developer tools f12 key go in the network tab when you click on submit the AJAX will be shown there you can check it is working or not and what response you are getting from it on clicking it. you can use alert("error") to check your javascript is working properly or not.

Comment: there is no respose when i click submit button.

Comment: you mean you can see the db.php and headers you are sending in network tab of deverloper tools but in response tab of the request, you are getting blank?

Comment: yes..i am getting blank

Comment: okay echo "hello"; die(); at the start of the db.php and check you are gettign hello in your response or not.

Comment: you will get hello and I am sure about that after that check your connection is correct or not it looks like a connection issue.

Comment: if the connection is also fine to write echo before your query variable and die after query finishes and you will get your query in response copy it and try to run it in MySQL check it is correct or not.

Comment: data has stored when i did not use ajax...if i remove ajax code it will work with page loaded

Comment: then try my ajax code I have posted in my answer because your javascript and ajax looks fine and  I have just changed the data part of the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

use developer tools f12 key go in the network tab when you click on submit the AJAX will be shown there you can check it is working or not and what response you are getting from it on clicking it. you can use alert("error") to check your javascript is working properly or not.

check the path of db.php is correct or not. in your case of the code it should be in the same folder where your Ajax running.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" action="db.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>



    </body>
    </html>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();

                if(name == '' && email =='')
                {
                    $('#result').html('<span>all fields are required</span>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url :"db.php",
                        method :"POST",
                        data :{'name':name,'email':email},                        
                        beforeSend:function(){
                            $('#result').html('<span>loading..!</span>');
                        },


                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

db.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sampl1");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "insert into jquery (name,email) values('$name','$email')";
$res =mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($res)
{
    echo "<p>you have entered</p>";
    echo "<p>name :".$[name]."</p>";
    echo "<p>email :".$[email]."</p>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @PrabhuRio ok please accept the answer :) your welcome

Comment: @PrabhuRio mark as correct, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                url :"what.php",
                method :"POST",
                data :$('#myform').serialize(),
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#result').html('<span>loading..!</span>');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }


            });
```

Remove that ';' after `data :$('#myform').serialize()` and put a comma instead. I answer this not knowing whether its a simple typo or a syntax issue.
in your php file:

```
echo "<p>name :".$name."</p>";
echo "<p>email :".$email."</p>";
```

Remove square brackets

Comment: it came like this  what i do    <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\sampl1\jqueryAjax\db.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

Comment: okay, but  I guess the ' nothing happens' is nolonger there. JS is sending the data to php successfully. Now in your php what is $[name] for? use $name and $email instead.

Comment: thank you .. it works...but the data did not store in the database..can you edit my code plz

Comment: anytime.You can accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: look at using prepared statements.And how to check for mysql errors using php.

Comment: i changed this statement ...if(isset($_POST['submit']))  into if(isset($_POST['name']))..it is working...but i dont know how it is working...can you explain

Comment: to find out what's happening, just put print_r($_POST);  before your if statement. Probably, serialise() does not include submit.You can start your research from there